# Android ParseException with SimpleDateFormat but JUnit test works?

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, parseexception

I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class DateUtil {
    private final static SimpleDateFormat origDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    private final static SimpleDateFormat reformatedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE., dd. MMM yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
    private final static String TAG = DateUtil.class.getSimpleName();

    public static String reformatDateString(String origDateString)  {
        String reformattedDateString = origDateString;
        try {
            Date parsedDate = origDateFormat.parse(origDateString);
            reformattedDateString = reformatedDateFormat.format(parsedDate);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            //if we can't parse the date, we don't change the format
            Log.i(TAG, "Parse exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return reformattedDateString;
    }

    public static boolean isBeforeCurrentDate(String dateString) throws ParseException  {
        Date parsedDate = origDateFormat.parse(dateString);

        if (parsedDate.before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())))  {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

...with its corresponding JUnit test:

```
public class DateUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void formatCorrectString() {
        String dateString = "Mon Sep 03 00:00:00 CEST 2007";
        String expectedResult = "Mo., 03. Sep 2007";

        String resultString = DateUtil.reformatDateString(dateString);

        assertEquals(expectedResult, resultString);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBeforeCurrentDate() throws ParseException  {
        String dateString = "Mon Sep 03 00:00:00 CEST 2007";

        assertTrue(DateUtil.isBeforeCurrentDate(dateString));
    }
}
```

This works. But on my Android application, I always get a ParseException with the same date string **Mon Sep 03 00:00:00 CEST 2007**. Any ideas what is going on here?

**[UPDATE]**
I figured out what is the problem. It's the timzone of the passed string. If I remove the "z" in the DateFormat and delete the timezone from the passed date string, it works in Android:

```
String dateString = zone.getEffectiveFrom().trim().replace("CEST", "").replace("GMT", "").replace("CET", "").replace("MESZ", "");
```

SimpleDateFormat: **EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy**
Passed string: **Mon Sep 03 00:00:00 2007**

This is just a workound and no solution, although I could live with that since I don't need the time of the date string, so it doesn't matter for me. But I'd like to know if this is a bug or if there is something special in Android?

Comment: are you completely sure that the app is passing in the exact same string ?

Comment: @RobertEstivill Yes, this is the output of logcat.
`11-23 20:53:20.287: I/DateUtil(617): Parse exception: Unparseable date: Mon Sep 03 00:00:00 CEST 2007`. I really don't understand why this happens.

Comment: How do you run your unit tests? As an android test project? I'm suspecting of the Locales used to instantiate the SimpleDateFormat, but not completely sure :s

Comment: @RobertEstivill I run this test as simple JUnit test in Eclipse with Run As->JUnit test (I commented out the line with Log.i for now to isolate the error, usually I use JMockIt to deal with that). And if I run it as local Maven build, it works too. But if I run the code as Application code (not as Android JUnit Test) on emulator, I get this ParseException.

Comment: Any solution?!?!?!?!?!?! I have the same the same thing happening for me. I am going nuts!

Comment: @StarWind What about the workaround?